# mapping an integer to an object in slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am using slick 3 with scala and play and I am wondering how can I transform, in the table definition, an ID into an object.

Let's say I have a list of values similar to an Enum in Java and the ID from database must correspond with the ID defined in Enum. It's similar to having another table in database which is referenced through that ID.

```
object X extends Table[(Int, String)]("x") {

  ...
  def typeId          = column[Int]("type_id")
  def type        = ... (AAA or BBB) // filled in by type_id
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Slick you can define your own projections (instead of the usual apply/unapply of case classes) from the data in your database to your objects and back again. You can also use a String to define your type in the database.

Your types might look like:

```
sealed trait X
case class AAA() extends X
case class BBB() extends X
```

Then your Slick mapping could look like this:

```
object Xs extends Table[X]("X") {
  def typeName = column[String]("TYPE_NAME")
  def toX(from: (String)): X = from match {
    case ("aaa") => AAA
    case ("bbb") => BBB
  }
  def fromX(x: X): (String) = x match {
    case AAA => ("aaa")
    case BBB => ("bbb")
  }
  override def * = (typeId) <> (toX, fromX)
}
```